A question on the ring $R$ of all eventually constant sequences $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$
Recall that an indecomposable $R$-module $M$ is a module that can't be written as the direct sum $M=A \oplus B$ of two nonzero submodules. Equivalently, the only summands of $M$ are $0$ and $M$.
Let $R$ be the ring of all eventually constant sequences $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Indeed, every element of $R$ is an idempotent. I claim that the only indecomposable summands of the module $R_R$ are the submodules of the form $e_k R$ where $e_k\in R$ is the sequence with $1$ in the $k$th position and $0$ otherwise. To prove this claim, I picked any indecomposable summand $A_R$ of $R_R$. Being a summand, it must be of the form $A=eR$ for some idempotent $e\in R$. If $e$ has $1$ in both the $i$th and $j$th positions ($i \neq j$), it turns out that $e_iR \oplus e_jR$ is a summand of $R_R$. Since $A$ is indecomposable, either $e_iR \oplus e_jR=0$ (which is of course impossible) or $A=e_iR \oplus e_jR$. Again, as $A_R$ is indecomposable, either $e_iR=0$ or $e_jR=0$, a clear contradiction.
Is this argument true?

What does the $\ldots$ in the last sentence mean? Potentially there could be infinitely many summands, which might not be defined (and is not directly related to the definition of decomposability).

Take for example $e=(0,1,1,1,\ldots)$. Then, in this case, $A=\bigoplus_{i=2}^\infty e_iR$. Can an indecomposable submodule be decomposed in such a way? Does not this contradict the indecomposability of $A$? (A module is indecomposable if does not contain proper nonzero summands, i.e., the only summands are $0$ and the module itself).

What is the (precise) definition of decomposable you are using? My guess is that it involves two summands, not an arbitrary number of (or infinitely many) summands.

This ring is in DaRT by the way.

It seems much more straightforward to just say
Because every cyclic submodule is a summand in this ring, irreducible right ideals of $R$ are simple.  For if $B$ is an ideal with nonzero element $e$, then $eB\oplus (1-e)B$ is a decomposition of $B$.  If $B$ is indecomposable, this says $B=eB=eR$ for all nonzero $e\in B$. That amounts to $B$ being simple.
Let $T$ be a simple right ideal of this $R$ and $t$ be a nonzero element of $T$.  Then $t$ is nonzero on some coordinate, so $e_i=e_it\in T\setminus\{0\}$ for some $i$.  But minimality implies $T=e_iR$. Thus all minimal ideals are "the obvious ones."

Excuse me, what is the relation between this argument and what I asked? Should an indecomposable summand be simple? May you please clarify the point of this answer?

@HusseinEid done.
